# Error 50007 when creating cgroup with cgroup_new_cgroup

Tags: c, docker, cgroups

I have a process running in a `docker container` (docker puts that processes in a cgroup btw). The process forks and I want to put some `forks` into `cgroups`.

I added the following code to my program:

```
cgroup_init();

struct cgroup *my_cgroup = cgroup_new_cgroup(cg_name);
cgroup_add_controller(my_cgroup, "cpu");

int cgroup_cr = cgroup_create_cgroup_from_parent(my_cgroup, 0);
```

The cgroup_r is 50007 ("Cgroup, operation not allowed"). I don't know why that is? Is there some **configuration** I need to change? Is a **capability** needed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe access to modify cgroups would allow a process to escape the docker container, so docker would disable that by default. You can test if the problem is with only a capability by running your container with:

```
docker run --cap-add=ALL ...
```

More than likely, you'll need a privilege like SYS_ADMIN and will be able to reduce the capabilities added to just your specific items.

If adding capabilities does not resolve your issue, you can remove all restrictions with:

```
docker run --privileged ...
```

More details can be found on:

- [Docker security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/)
- [Runtime privileges](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities)

Comment: Actually, I have found the problem to be something completely else, but your answer was the missing link: the program itself used libcap to drop capabilities (as root) and couldn't access the cgroup fs any longer. Adding CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE to the cap-list solved the problem.